# How to open external Url outside the inappbrowser and not inside the Inapp browser

Tags: ionic3, inappbrowser

i wrapped a website in ionic inapp browser in which the website contains some external site which has to be opened in system browser and i don’t have any idea how to open it in system browser.

any idea of how to achieve it ? the external sites should open in system browser instead of native inapp browser.

```
export class HomePage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private iab: InAppBrowser, public 
platform: Platform, 
private fileOpener: FileOpener, private transfer: FileTransfer, private 
file: File) {
platform.ready().then(() => {

let browser = 
this.iab.create('https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/index.htm','_blank', 
{zoom:'yes',location:'no'});

browser.show();
 });
 }
```

There are fb links and instagram links which i wanted to open outside the inappbrowser i.e in System browser.

i know this java method window.open() we can open links in system browser but i don't know how to do in appbrowser.

Any suggestions and help would be much appreaciated.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter of `iab.create()` is target. You should use `_system` as target parameter like below:

```
 this.iab.create('your_link','_system', your_options);
```

Comment: But this will make everything to open in system browser right ?

Comment: If you are handling all link clicks with InAppBrowser. Theoretically, yes.

Comment: No ! actually i only want certain links to be opened outside the inAppbrowser.....like facebook links and instagram links to be opened outside the inappbrowser